# Fiido D2: shock absorber broken

Tags: repair, electric-bike, replacement, folding-bicycle, shocks

I bought almost an year ago a [Fiido D2 bike](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32897842363.html). I use it everyday for my commute to work and unfortunately it broke.

I brought it to a bike repairer and he said that there's nothing he can do. The only solution is to buy a new one.

My problem is that I can't find it online, I googled a lot about it but no shock absorbers of the Fiido D2 found.

Does anyone can suggest me where I can find this shock absorber replacement?

Answer (score 8):

Your best bet would be to contact the manufacturer for specifications or even replacement parts. Failing that, your next best thing should be to measure/learn parameters of your current shock, and then finding another ones that matches closely these parameters.

What you need to measure/find out are:
[image: Stroke and length]

- Eye-to-eye length
- Stroke length
- Mounting hardware used to mount it into the frame and related parameters. such as diameters of mounting holes
- Air pressure or coil firmness values

See e.g. this [article](https://www.worldwidecyclery.com/blogs/worldwide-cyclery-blog/the-basics-to-upgrading-the-rear-shock-on-you-mountain-bike)

Comment: On a $450US bike from a brand that does not have a web presence, just products sold through Amazon I doubt that the 'shock absorber' really is one, it's probably just a spring in a tube. However, amazon seems to have plenty of such units for under $50US, so just find one the right length and bolt it on!